# Scheduled activity is never run

Tags: corda

I have defined a `SchedulableState` as follows:

```
class MySchedulableState() : SchedulableState {
    override val participants = listOf<Party>()

    val nextActivityTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + 100)

    override fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity? {
        return ScheduledActivity(flowLogicRefFactory.create("com.template.ScheduledFlow", thisStateRef), nextActivityTime)
    }
}
```

However, when I create this state in a flow, the scheduled activity is never run. Wh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your node uses the state's constructor to recreate the state every time you extract it from the vault. As part of constructing the state, `Instant.now()` is called again and assigned to `nextActivityTime`, pushing the scheduled event into the future.

Instead, you should define your `SchedulableState` as follows:

```
class MySchedulableState(val now: Instant) : SchedulableState {
    override val participants = listOf<Party>()

    val nextActivityTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.toEpochMilli() + 100)

    override fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity? {
        return ScheduledActivity(flowLogicRefFactory.create("com.template.ScheduledFlow", thisStateRef), nextActivityTime)
    }
}
```

Note how we pass the current time in the constructor. This value will not change every time the state is reconstructed (note that it must be a `val` to ensure it is serialised).